# Can I get data from consul without having agent on my pc

Tags: c#, consul

Is there any way to get data from consul server, without having agent running on my machine. Could I make the C# code interact directly with consul server instead of using the running agent on my machine.
Also if anyone used consul in c# before, can you recommend any documentation, because I couldn't find any so far.

Comment: Did you try searching the web for "consul .net api"?

Comment: Yes I tried it first and did you see what you get when searching the web for it ?

Comment: Yes, lots of libraries that wrap Consul's HTTP API.

Comment: Do not vandalize your own posts. If you feel the post has no merit, delete it. Deleting a lot of posts can block you from posting new ones but vandalizing your posts gets you to that block in no-time, so **don't do it**.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get any data from remote consul instance via it's [HTTP API](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http.html). You can find a list of client implementations [here](https://www.consul.io/downloads_tools.html).

Comment: Thanks, just when I go to the HTTP API I cant find anything related to C# /.Net , if I go to the client implentations when I click at C# implementation it leads me to the nuget package download site.
Currently I am reading the classes and trying to understand the implementation by the name of the class ,but this is not very efficient :/

Comment: read unit tests